# Limit of time integral of brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Can someone help explain the following,

$$
\lim \limits_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t W_u\, du=\lim \limits_{t \to 0} \frac{W_0t}{t}=W_0=0\,?
$$

Thanks!

Comment: If $W_t$ is supposed to be a Brownian motion then this is not true as stated - the limit on the left side diverges with probability 1.  Are you sure you are asking the right question?

Comment: For each state $\omega$ the left-hand side is the integral of a continuous function. Given $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta$ such that if $|x-0|<\delta$ then $|W_x-W_0|<\epsilon$. Therefore, for $|t|<\delta$ $|W_x|<|W_0|+\epsilon$. Therefore $|\int_{0}^tW_t|\leq (|W_0|+\epsilon)\cdot t\to0$ as $t\to 0$. I don't know what they did in the first equality above.

Comment: oops sorry! i made a typo and excluded a 1/t in front on the LHS. fixed it

Comment: That changes things a little bit, but the same work solves the question. I guess what they did in the first equation is to write (informally) the estimation $|\int_{0}^t W_x|\leq (|W_0|+\epsilon)\cdot t$. Then the $t$'s cancel but since this is for all $\epsilon$ and $|W_0|=0$, the limit is still zero.

Comment: is it just $W_u \, du = W_0t $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t f(u) \, du = f(0)$$

for any continuous function $f$. Applying this to $f(t) := W_t$ yields the result.

Answer (score 1):

L'hopital? The limit is a $\frac{0}{0}$ type, so if we let $f(t) = \int_0^t W_udu$

$$\lim_{t\to0} \dfrac{f(t)}{t} = \lim_{t\to0} \dfrac{f'(t)}{1}$$

using fundamental calculus theorem  $$f(t) = \int_0^tW_udu \implies f'(t)=W_t$$

$$\therefore \lim_{t\to0} \dfrac{f'(t)}{1} = \lim_{t\to0}W_t = W_0$$